# Windows 7 login issues

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

I have one user who has been having this issue I have never seen before. She is always having issues starting up her machine, such as Windows getting stuck on welcome screen after logging in, or stuck on applying updates. We always had to force the machine down and start up again and she is able to login right after. It's becoming a frequent occurrence and the constant force shutdown doesn't seem to be a great solution.

However there is now a new issue, when she logs in, in the morning, she is faced with a Switch user screen. She types in her password. presses enter or the arrow and nothing happens, she is able to edit the password still, and the computer seems to be responsive. If she clicks Switch user, the dialog goes away as if it were loading the next screen, but never does and essentially freezes. A force shutdown thereafter remedies this and she is able to login afterwards.

We are in a Active Directory environment. I've tried searching for this issue online and cannot find anything.

Comment: Does she or the computer have a start up/log in script that could be failing?

Comment: Why are you troubleshooting this from the perspective of the user? It seems very much like something is wrong with the machine. If possible re-image and provide a replacement machine for the duration.

Comment: like a group policy setting? We have 15 computers in the domain all essentially the same, with the same policy. I also checked her event log and haven't found anything interesting.

Is there a place to check for specific scripts?

Comment: Does the Windows 7 computer is up-to-date (SP1 + updates)?

Comment: I think I may have found the issue, I wrote a policy a while ago trying to rename the local admin account from Admin to LocalAdmin, it never really worked, I can see on her machine under Group Policy Results, under Local Users and Groups "Result: Failure (Error Code: 0x800708c5)", I will remove that policy and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check for any user or computer log in/start up scripts that might be failing.  One of those might be looking for some kind of interaction or be pausing to display some kind of error.